# Iron-Router flickering issue

Tags: coffeescript, meteor, iron-router

According to the Iron-Router Documentation, this is how you can handle routing when trying to route to a page that has no data associated with it.

```
if Meteor.isClient
    Router.onBeforeAction('dataNotFound')

Router.map ->

    @route 'chat',
        path: '/chat/:room_name'
        notFoundTemplate: 'home'
        data: ->
            Rooms.findOne({room_name: @params.room_name})
```

My code specifically is designed to redirect to the home page when a specific chat room is not defined. It works as expected with one very annoying issue. There is a lot of page flickering going on. The hooks seems to be rendering the `home` page first than following through with the logic to land you on the right page.

So when visiting a chat room that does exists, it quickly renders the home page for a split second, than loads the room. When visiting a chat room that doesn't exist, it is rendering the home page, than quickly re-rendering it. In both cases there is a flicker happening that makes these pages very annoying to use.

Am I just doing this in the wrong way? Or is there a better way to avoid the flickering?

**EDIT: This only happens on a hard page reload**

Here is my updated code based on the first answer, but I am having an issue where every `room_name` is being rendered and the ones that dont exist aren't being redirected to `home`

**Routes:** Which exists in the root level outside of client/server folders

```
if Meteor.isClient
    Router.onBeforeAction('dataNotFound')

Router.map ->

    roomExists = undefined
    @route 'chat',
        path: '/chat/:room_name'
        notFoundTemplate: 'home'
        onBeforeAction: ->
            @subscribe('rooms').wait()
        data: ->
            Rooms.findOne({room_name: @params.room_name})
```

**Server Code**

```
Meteor.publish 'rooms', () ->
    Room.find({})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also subscribe in the helper using the following pattern:

```
Template.someTemplate.helper = function() {
    var ready = Meteor.subscribe('somePublish').ready();
    var data = collection.find({_id: this.id});

    return {
        ready: ready,
        data: data
    };
};
```

In the template html you would then do this:

```
{{#with helper}}
    {{#if ready}}
        {{Dostuff with your data}}
    {{else}}
        {{>spinner}} Loading...
    {{/if}}
{{/with}}
```

Using the subscribes in the router stops the whole page from loading, while in most cases only a few sections of that page actually depend on that subscription being ready.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason for that behavior is the subscription not being ready when the page is rendered the first time. The fix is to move your subscriptions to the router and wait on them:

```
Router.map ->

  @route 'chat',
    path: '/chat/:room_name'
    notFoundTemplate: 'home'
    onBeforeAction: ->
      @subscribe('chatRooms').wait()
    data: ->
      Rooms.findOne({room_name: @params.room_name})
```

Comment: I feel like this is what I should be doing, but having just implemented it I am having an issue. Now I am back to where every single `chat/:room_name` loads even if it is not in the database. What  parameter needs to be passed to subscribe for this to work properly?

Comment: If you just want to fetch just the current chat room, pass `@params.room_name`.